# Errors pulling all photos using Facebook Graph API

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am putting together [a script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Abbotta4/fb_pull/main/fb_pull.py) that will pull every photo I am in and every photo I have uploaded. I used `me?fields=name,photos{album,link,created_time,name}` as my query to get my name and all my photos, where each photo details the album it is in, a link to the photo, the time it was uploaded, and the name of the photo. This query gives me 25 photos and a pager that I can user to access the next or previous 25 photos.

This seems to work for a couple pages, but then I get an error:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#200) Missing Permissions', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 200, 'fbtrace_id': 'Ask3IRry6h7Cm3PuZHp_76P'}}
```

My token has the user_photos, user_videos, and user_posts permissions, so I'm not sure what else I would be missing to cause this error. I added all 50 permissions that I could and tried again. This time, I got:

```
{'error': {'message': '(#100) Pages Public Content Access requires either app secret proof or an app token', 'type': 'OAuthException', 'code': 100, 'fbtrace_id': 'AzNJPWqlBjuoL0ys-hRw37c'}}
```

I generated the appsecret_proof token [using the method described here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/), but the result was yet another error having to do with pages.

What is the correct way to pull photos? What permissions am I missing to do this?